# Type error and mismatch for vba split function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a variable defined in string as below

```
Dim stringValue As String
Dim stringArray As String

stringValue = "3,4,5"
stringArray = Split(stringValue,",")
```

I am not sure what is going wrong here, but the when it goes through the Split function, it gives out

> error ["Type error 13, Mismatch type"]

Answer (score 2):

You want to define your `stringArray` as a `Variant`, so that it can take on the properties of an array.

```
Dim stringValue As String
Dim stringArray As Variant

stringValue = "3,4,5"
stringArray = Split(stringValue,",")
```

or define it as a string array from the start:

```
Dim stringValue As String
Dim stringArray() As String

stringValue = "3,4,5"
stringArray = Split(stringValue,",")
```

and for that matter, since your example is so simple, you could also do it like this:

```
Dim stringArray As Variant
stringArray = Array("3", "4", "5")
```

Comment: Sorry I mistyped, but I was using stringArray() only.

Comment: I meant to say I am getting the error after I use stringArray() only

Comment: You must have some other code you did not include in your question that is interfering with it then. Did you try my examples in a test subroutine all by itself?